# Removing Duplicates in an ArrayList by creating a Method

Tags: java, arraylist

I have to write a method called removeDups that accepts an ArrayList of Strings and returns a copy of the ArrayList with all the duplicates removed. I have to return a new ArrayList with no duplicate basically.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Duplicates {
    public static ArrayList <String> removeDups(ArrayList<String> myArray) {
        for (String item: myArray ) {
            ArrayList <String> noDuplicate = new ArrayList <String>();
            if (!noDuplicate.contains(item)) {
                noDuplicate.add(item);
                }else
                    ;
                return noDuplicate;
        }   
    }
}
```

As a beginner coder, I am having trouble writing this code.

Comment: Should you be creating a new list for each element in `myArray`? Should you be returning right away or after having processed all the elements?

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify few things to make it work (and to have cleaner code):

- when you do not need `ArrayList<String>` you should work with interface `List<String>`
- you should initiate `noDuplicate` array in the first line of method
- you should check the condition `!noDuplicate.contains(item)` and if so just add `item` to `noDuplicate` list
- rename the method from `removeDups` to `removeDuplicates`

Working code:

```
public static List<String> removeDuplicates(List<String> myArray) {
    List<String> noDuplicate = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String item : myArray) {
        if (!noDuplicate.contains(item)) {
            noDuplicate.add(item);
        }
    }
    return noDuplicate;
}
```

If you will take a look on Java streams you can do the same thing using:

```
List<String> noDuplicate = myArray.stream()
            .distinct()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I am happy that I could help you. Good luck with Java bro! :)